# Finding numbers who digits ^ (digit position) == original number i.e. (89 = 8^1 + 9^2), but the code won't return anything higher than 1306?

Tags: python

```
def sum_dig_pow(a, b): 
    return [i for i in range(a, b + 1) if sum([int(x) ** (str(i).index(x) + 1) for x in str(i)]) == i]
```

sum_dig_pow(1, 2000) gets every answer for 1 to 1306 and then none above that?

Comment: `int(x) ** (str(i).index(x) + 1)` this is wrong, for a start. That's only going to give you the index of the first instance of any given digit. `'1123'.index('1')` will always evaluate to `0`.

Comment: Beyond that? I'm no mathematician and I'm not familiar with this problem, but are you sure that there are any numbers that match the pattern, and are in the range `[1307-2000]`?

Comment: I would encourage you to fix the title of the question to something written in english (no code), and then explain it further in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your code doesn't work, because the missing solution 1676 contains two times the 6. So `str(i).index(x)` will return the wrong index for the second 6 which makes the calculation faulty.

I guess, this is one of the times, where I'd start without list comprehensions and first get the code to work. Is this generally the result you want?

```
def sum_dig_pow(a, b): 
    result = []
    for number in range(a, b+1):
        calculation = 0
        for position, digit in enumerate(map(int, str(number))):
            calculation += digit**(position + 1)
        if calculation == number:
            result += [number]
    return result

print(sum_dig_pow(1, 2000))
```

Which prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 89, 135, 175, 518, 598, 1306, 1676]
```

Then reduce it to:

```
def sum_dig_pow(a, b): 
    result = []
    for number in range(a, b+1):
        calculation = sum([digit**(position + 1) for position, digit in enumerate(map(int, str(number)))])
        if calculation == number:
            result += [number]
    return result
```

And then to:

```
def sum_dig_pow(a, b): 
    return [number for number in range(a, b+1) if sum([digit**(position + 1) for position, digit in enumerate(map(int, str(number)))]) == number]
```

But I think it remains questionable why you would want to write this with list comprehensions only? You could at least use a one-liner then ;-)

```
sum_dig_pow = lambda a, b: [number for number in range(a, b+1) if sum([digit**(position + 1) for position, digit in enumerate(map(int, str(number)))]) == number]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer man, I've been having a lot of trouble with index() for this exact reason, I'll definitely start using enumerate more often.